# IOS : How to run a method in Background when app is killed

Tags: ios, objective-c

Can anyone tell me how to run method in background when app is killed, actually i want to get the time continuously for a specific scenario when date is changed, then on specific time i want to show an alert or notify to user that you forgot to checkout. How i will be able to do it. Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at [local notifications](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH102-SW9)?

Answer (score 3):

For this you would have to create local notifications.

**Local notifications and push notifications are ways for an application that isn’t running in the foreground to let its users know it has information for them. The information could be a message, an impending calendar event, or new data on a remote server. When presented by the operating system, local and push notifications look and sound the same. They can display an alert message or they can badge the application icon. They can also play a sound when the alert or badge number is shown.** according to [Notifications Introduction Apple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction.html)

You could check their [Notifications section on the Apple website](https://developer.apple.com/notifications/)

Please go through these tutorials to further enhance your knowledge and implement the notifications.

[ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial - I](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-local-notification-tutorial/)

[iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications - II](http://www.icodeblog.com/2010/07/29/iphone-programming-tutorial-local-notifications/)

[local-notifications-tutorial-add-a-local-notification-to-your-iphone-app - III](http://www.theappcodeblog.com/2011/04/28/local-notifications-tutorial-add-a-local-notification-to-your-iphone-app/)
Hope these help.

Answer (score 1):

On `applicationWillResignActive` You can start background task with  `[application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil]` for undefined time. You get some time to do something. After you finished you must close background task with `[application endBackgroundTask:identifier];`

```
   - (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
    {
        if ([[[ASDimChatManager sharedManager] user] uid]) {
            UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier identifier = [application beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:nil];
            //your cod here
                [application endBackgroundTask:identifier];

        }
    }
```